# Error in Sharepoint 2013 content query

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I'm adding a content query in the master page and every time I will customize it returns the following error:
[image: Error SPD 2013]

Someone could help me or explain me why this error happens?

I tried doing the content query in a page layout and the same error happens.

Comment: I think you have to check the [ULS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210652.aspx) log for that _Correlation ID_.

Comment: I looked at the log and returned error is very generic, impossible to identify where the problem really this

Comment: As generic as it may be, your problem is very hard to solve without as much information as possible :) like what query are you using? What customizations are made in the farm? And so on

Comment: We do need some more info. Could you maybe add some of your code/steps you did to configure it? It might help us help you out.

Comment: You can try iisreset

Comment: May I ask why you are adding a CQWP to the master page, as this will invoke the query on each page load everywhere in the site ?

Comment: Also, have you tried adding the WP to the page layout or directly in a page instead, to check if it has to do with the fact it is contained in the master page ?

Answer (score 2):

I followed these steps and managed to solve the problem. Thanks guys

[Content Query Web Part Key cannot be null](http://planet-sharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/content-query-web-part-key-cannot-be.html)

> Very useful error message!!!! There is a conflict with the Developer
>   Feature in SharePoint 2013 which appears to break the content query
>   web part. Not so hot if you are relying on using this web part on your
>   development site where you need the development feature to be
>   available.
>
> To resolve this issue you will need to disable the feature,
>   unfortunately it is a hidden feature so you will need to disable this
>   via SharePoint 2013 management shell. The powershell script below
>   should help, run this, it will disable the SharePoint 2013 developer
>   feature and Viola you have a working Content Query web part.
>
> ------- Start disable developer feature command -------------
>
> Disable-SPFeature -identity  "E374875E-06B6-11E0-B0FA-57F5DFD72085"
>   -URL `http://yoursiteurl`
>
> ------- Endable developer feature command -------------
>
> Once you have configured your content query web part you can
>   re-enable the developer feature if required using the script below.
>
> ------- Start enable developer feature command -------------
>
> enable-SPFeature -identity "E374875E-06B6-11E0-B0FA-57F5DFD72085" -URL
>
> ### `http://yoursiteurl`    ------- End enable developer feature command
>
> Hopefully we will see a fix in the next Cumulative update for this
>   issue, I'm sure there will be more.

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution, link only answers are typically frowned upon. I've taken the liberty to copy the pertinent part of the related blog post into your answer so it doesn't get lost.